# How to view sections & addresses of .bin and .hex files in Linux?

Tags: linux, binary-files, hexadecimal, reverse-engineer

I have started reversing a binary. I dumped the contents as hex using xxd into a file I made with extension .hex,  then used objdump to disassemble that .hex file into assembly code, and put this into a .txt file.

Is there a way using terminal to view sections & addresses of `.bin` and `.hex` files in Linux? - This would help me in the reversing of the binary / hex data in the files.

I have come across the `size` command, but this cannot handle `.bin` or `.hex` files - `File format not recognised`

Comment: `.bin` and `.hex` files do not have sections. The just have addresses which are equal to the byte index. If they'd have some kind of format, their file extension would usually be different.

Comment: Do you mean [Intel hex format files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX#File_example), or do you mean executable files (like [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)), or do you generally mean files with binary data? Lots of tools exist for all of those (`hexdump`, `objdump`, `biew`, reverse engineering tools like `binwalk` or `radare2`).

Comment: Not sure - maybe the latter. I have updated the question to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim's `:%!xxd` command to view a file in a hex editor-like mode.  While it's far from the best thing out there for editing binary files, it's certainly suitable for browsing a hex file and jumping to specific addresses.  If you use this mode, do note that the file is still being edited as if it were a text file; I would recommend another solution for editing.

Comment: Ok that is for viewing contents of a file though. My question is asking for terminal command that outputs sections and addresses of a hex or bin file.